# Disabling "pylint(line-too-long)" in setup.cfg

Tags: installation, python-module, pylint, flake8

I want to disable "pylint(line-too-long)" from my setup.cfg file but it does not seem to pick up the settings.

In my setup.cfg i have other module settings, one of which is flake8 and that one picks up the codes that i want to ignore but not pylint.

This is the pylint part of the file:
`[pylint] disable = unreachable, missing-function-docstring, missing-module-docstring,  prefer-logging-interpolation, line-too-long`

Is there something here that i am missing or doing wrong so the disable is not being picked up?

Thanks!

I have tried disabling the line-too-long with "disable = line-too-long" and also by entering a code in flake8 ignore list which did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly add configuration to the `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.pylint]
disable = ["line-too-long"]
```

If you want to use ini the syntax here's an example of `pylintrc` file:

https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/main/examples/pylintrc

If you want to add multiple tools settings in `setup.cfg` (you should not, you should move to `pyproject.toml` instead, which is why only the pyproject.toml is documented. flake8 is the only project I know not supporting `pyproject.toml` in 2023), this is the syntax:

```
[pylint.messages control]
disable = unreachable, missing-function-docstring, missing-module-docstring,  prefer-logging-interpolation, line-too-long
```

Comment: Wow thanks! This worked!
As a beginner i am wondering why certain settings (like black and pylint) need to be in the "pyproject.toml" instead of in the setup.cfg?

For example, i have "MyPy" and "Darglint" in my setup.cfg aswell, would their settings not get picked up?

Comment: ``setup.cfg`` is an 'old' convention, it will be replaced by PEP 621 https://peps.python.org/pep-0621/. depending on the lib maintainers some way to configure the tools are supported or not. black was created not so long ago so it support only pyproject.toml, old tools like pylint did the whole "our own file" (pylintrc), then "setup.cfg" when it was hype, then "pyproject.toml" cycle. But tools might want to drop the old conventions at some point.